# Getting DataTables to display ColVis buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using the DataTables Jquery library I have a table with about 30 columns I would like to hide/display various columns. I have included all the appropriate JS and CSS files.

My Jquery code is

```
$('#rollupTable').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "colReorder": true,
                buttons: ['colvis'],
                select: true,
                "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
                ],
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 1
                }
            });
```

The buttons are not displaying. How do I get the buttons to display? Do I need to add definitions or does it pick that up from the table itself?

Comment: That plugin has been deprecated for a long time. Consider moving on to something that is supported.

Comment: Like @Ohgodwhy said, you should definitely switch to the new "buttons" plugin for datatables. Having said that, you need to add something like this `"dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'` after this `"scrollX": true,`